# Java is running even after it is disabled

Tags: virus, java, firefox

To prevent adds and pop-up that seduce users to install or download viruses I have disabled Java. But I have noticed that even with Java disables Firefox is still running it. The pop-ups are coming up. I even tried switching it to Private Mode just to see and ti still allowed the Java to run. This happened since the last update. Anyone out there have an answer? Is this a bug in Firefox or is Java running some new script that can't be disabled? Or is there another browser out there that is more secure?

Comment: Is it possible that you are confusing java and javascript?

Comment: I may well be. I am not really a security IT guy. This has just been kind of thrown on me and I am trying to make it as secure as I can without just locking everything down. 
If this is the case do you have any advice?

Comment: What operating system and how exactly did you disable it? Unless you disabled it through the Control Panel Applet on Windows then you didn't disable it right.  We are talking about Java not Javascript right?

Comment: This doesn't sound like either a Java or Javascript issue to me.  This sounds like adware.

Answer (score 3):

Java and JavaScript are not the same.  They aren't even related.  JavaScript is an interpreted scripting language that is used by websites to automate site behavior and interactivity on the client side.  Java is an actual computer language that is run by a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and is used for applications or occasionally applets that may be embedded into a website.  JavaScript is what is disabled by the browser.  For Java you would need to change the settings for the Java add-in for your browser.  It will be called "Java Platform something-or-other", depending on your version when in Firefox.

Update: If these are disabled or not installed already, then you probably already have adware on your system that is causing the pop-ups by actually asking the browser to load them directly.  Try running something like Malware Bytes to see if it finds anything.

Comment: It is the 23.0.1 and there are no Java Plugins to disable. I am at a loss to know what to ask next.

Comment: @Will - if you can post a screen shot of the popup that would help.

Comment: I think the correct thing to do a that point is not post a screenshot or mess with the system but get the (direct) help from someone how knows what he is doing: contact your system administrator

Comment: OK thanks to all the post. Yeah I have tried all of this now and it is still happening. I will install Malware Bytes and try that. I never thought of a virus doing it. Thanks again. !!